# Build List From Functions In Haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell

I'm new to Haskell so I apologize if this is an easy question, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

What I would like to do is grab the first and last element of a list and return those in a new list.

I know that `head [1,2,3,4]` will return `1`, and I know that `last [1,2,3,4]` will return `4`. But how would I go about placing those two results into a list such as: `[1,4]`?

Thanks.

Comment: If you know that you want exactly 2 results, then it is better to use a 2-tuple rather than a 2-element list. e.g. `(1,4)` instead of `[1,4]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can place elements into a list using list notation syntax:

```
firstLast1 xs = [head xs, last xs]
```

which is syntactic sugar for using the list constructor directly:

```
firstLast2 xs = head xs : last xs : []
```

However, both of these will fail with a runtime error when an empty list is passed.  You can guard against this by pattern-matching:

```
firstLast3 [] = []
firstLast3 xs = [head xs, last xs]
```

Comment: With that pattern matching, it would seem reasonable to also add the case `firstLast3 [x] = [x]`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout - possibly, although there's an open question as to whether the intended behavior is `firstLast3 [x] = [x]` or `firstLast3 [x] = [x,x]`.  If the latter, it may also make sense to change the return type to a `Maybe [a]`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to look at [Maybe](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Maybe.html) to avoiding empty list case.

```
headAndLast :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
headAndLast [] = Nothing
headAndLast x = Just [head x, last x]
```

And

```
> headAndLast [1,2,3]
Just [1,3]
```

Comment: Why the `Num` constraint?  I also think it would be more useful to have a function `headAndLast :: [a] -> Maybe [a]`.  Composition with `sequence` may be the most convenient way to do this.

Comment: That `Num` constraint is weird; why do you need it? Also, some hacks you may or may not enjoy: `lastM = headM . reverse; headAndLast' :: [a] -> Maybe [a]; headAndLast' = liftM2 (\x y -> [x,y]) headM lastM`.

Comment: Daniel, looks like type of `liftM2 (\x y -> [x,y]) headM lastM` is `[Maybe a]`, but not `Maybe [a]`

Comment: I'm not sure why you would prefer `Maybe [a]` over `Maybe (a,a)`.

Comment: @pat, topic-starter want to get `[1,4]` from `[1,2,3,4]`, not `(1,4)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let xs = [1, 2, 3, 4] in [head xs, last xs]
```

Comment: As John L. mentioned above, that version will fail if xs is [].